# Site-specific close reasons [update 2022]

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Now we're a fully-fledged site, albeit one that kind of scraped through in a grandfathered style, can we have our own custom close reasons?

If we can, perhaps we could discuss favourite candidates?

- Requests for external resources - shopping questions, but not just hardware, things such as cropped up today - in effect where can I get this sample… https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/50176/what-is-this-build-up-sound-effect
- Simple "how to operate my… X" or "How do I connect X to *completely mismatched* Y?"

I don't see these as having any lasting benefit for anyone.

Comments, suggestions, other ideas…?

Presumably, anything we do add as a close reason would need to also be added to our [Help pages](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help) too.

I realise we've had questions similar to this in the past, but I'm still hoping we can gain enough traction to actually enact some of these…

[Zero-effort off topic](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/zero-effort-off-topic)

[Customer Support questions](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/customer-support-questions)